# Ethereum gas estimation error Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"gas required exceeds allowance (5679)","id":4794992682579589}

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I deployed contract and transfer all tokens to CA
https://etherscan.io/token/0x9f874f5f911f5e794ff1c8c152f05c5b9d0e5f26
Then i tried to call opentrading functions but failed with this in Remix:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"gas required exceeds allowance (5679)","id":4794992682579589}

Here is opentrading function:

```
function openTrading() external onlyOwner() {
    require(!tradingOpen,"trading is already open");
    uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _tTotal);
    uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
    uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(address(this),balanceOf(address(this)),0,0,owner(),block.timestamp);
    IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(address(uniswapV2Router), type(uint).max);
    swapEnabled = true;
    tradingOpen = true;
    firstBlock = block.number;
}
```

What happened and how can i open trade on this token?

I spent .15 on fails lol. help me pls to open trade this